# I need to accept from input file and that may be of any format in C# . i need to check the format and extract year

Tags: c#, .net, date-format

The format YYYYMMDD is not being accepted and is throwing an exception
i tried using

```
string Year = DateTime.ParseExact(UseDate, "YYYYMMDD",
              CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Year.ToString();
```

Do only i need to use a date variable ? and how does the date format yyyymmdd gets processed?

Comment: What **is** the exception?

Comment: what is your input that you are trying to parse?

Comment: The input is a file .... i need to extract a date from that . and find out what the format is and accordingly need to extract the year . the exception is : String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Comment: If it can be in any format why are you using ParseExact?

Comment: So what's the string? Also Given you are using InvariantCulture, waht culture have you set in the assembly?

Comment: Because i need the year from that date. and i guess i need the format for that

Comment: The string is 20130101 how do i get the year from this ? I gues i complicated the whole thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tested this and this works fine

```
DateTime temp;
if (DateTime.TryParseExact("20130101", "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out temp))
{
     string year = temp.Year.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Yes . Worked .Thank you . But how do i find out what format is the input date in ?

Comment: Well i guess you can't, you need to know beforehand what format you need to parse.

Answer (score 1):

You can define any format you like - plus you can get a list of defaults for a given culture.

```
var ci = new CultureInfo("en-US");
var formats = new[] { "M-d-yyyy", "dd-MM-yyyy", "MM-dd-yyyy", "M.d.yyyy", "dd.MM.yyyy", "MM.dd.yyyy" }
        .Union(ci.DateTimeFormat.GetAllDateTimePatterns()).ToArray();

DateTime.ParseExact("07/23/2013", formats, ci, DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal).Dump();
DateTime.ParseExact("07-23-2013", formats, ci, DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal).Dump();
DateTime.ParseExact("23-07-2013", formats, ci, DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal).Dump();
DateTime.ParseExact("23.07.2013", formats, ci, DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal).Dump();
```

**Output:**

```
7/23/2013 12:00:00 AM
7/23/2013 12:00:00 AM
7/23/2013 12:00:00 AM
7/23/2013 12:00:00 AM
```

Comment: am not sure on how to use this code in the program .
can you please elaborate about cultureinfo or can i get a link where i can get more about this and using date formats?

Answer (score 0):

The format string of `DateTime.ParseExact` is case sensitive.

```
string year =  DateTime.ParseExact(UseDate, "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Year.ToString();
```

The `M`'s are uppercase because that means month whereas `m` means minute.

[**Custom Date and Time Format Strings**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
string Year = 
DateTime.ParseExact(UseDate, "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Year.ToString();
```

Year y and Day d must be lowercase, and Month M must be uppercase